# Keyboard shortcuts for Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I wanted to know is there any keyboard shortcut to clear **specific** cell output in databricks.

As of now i can see there is option to hide the result.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, this is currently not possible, it's all or nothing sadly.

However a workaround I've found for this, is adding an empty cell below the cell you want to clear the output for. Then click the left blue line of the cell (to select the cell and not its contents) and then press SHIFT + M (merge with cell below).

Comment: This looks a good workaround as of now:)